# buffered Image rendering in ejs

Tags: image, ejs

I am rending my buffered image into ejs but it si showing stream of values and not an image.

I am using the following code

```
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;{<%- bufs -%>}" />
```

The output is just a jumbled stream os values.

I tied using <%= but it gives the following error

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in /home/ubuntu/workspace/MissingPeople/v1/views/report_missing.ejs while compiling ejs
```

Kindly help. The image is being extracted from DB and passed to ejs

Answer (score 0):

It worked with the following syntax

```
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%- result2[0] -%>">
```

<%- is working but <%= is not working

I am not sure about the reason for it though.

Regards
Gaurav